# Languages spoken by wild-shaped druid

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e

When a druid turns into an elemental, which languages can he speak?

Does the new form allow him to still speak his already known languages or the physical changes of the vocal chords don't allow that anymore?

In this case, what if the druid doesn't know the language of the new elemental form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Pathfinder

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-

> A druid loses her ability to speak while in **animal form** because she is limited to the sounds that a normal, untrained animal can make, but she can communicate normally with other animals of the same general grouping as her new form.

(emphasis mine)

> At 6th level, a druid can use wild shape to change into a Large or Tiny animal or a Small elemental. When taking the form of an animal, a druid's wild shape now functions as beast shape II. When taking the form of an elemental, the druid's wild shape functions as elemental body I.

So, the "vocal chord changes" don't prohibit her from speaking while Wild Shaped into an elemental. Therefore, it's off to the Elemental Body description...

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/elemental-body

... which says nothing about languages, one way or the other. Elementals can speak (granted, just their native tongue, but the *can* speak). Therefore, RAW would seem to imply that Wild Shaping Druids can continue to speak while in Elemental form.

## 3.5e

http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#wildShape

> A druid loses her ability to speak while in animal form because she is limited to the sounds that a normal, untrained animal can make, but she can communicate normally with other animals of the same general grouping as her new form

So, again, the 3.5 Druid can't speak while in Animal form.

> At 16th level, a druid becomes able to use wild shape to change into a Small, Medium, or Large elemental (air, earth, fire, or water) once per day. These elemental forms are in addition to her normal wild shape usage. In addition to the normal effects of wild shape, the druid gains all the elemental’s extraordinary, supernatural, and spell-like abilities. She also gains the elemental’s feats for as long as she maintains the wild shape, but she retains her own creature type.

Elemental Form does note that it applies "the normal effects of Wild Shape". I would read "the normal effects" as covering the duration, HP regeneration, and gear melding; the inability to speak seems to be specific to Animal Form.

## Conclusion

As I read them, RAW would allow a Druid to speak any languages she knows normally while Wild Shaped into an Elemental, but that Wild Shaping would *not* grant the elemental's native tongue.

Answer (score 3):

> Except as described elsewhere, the creature retains all other game statistics of its original form

Because with alternate form,

> The creature gains the physical ability scores (Str, Dex, Con) of its new form. It retains the mental ability scores (Int, Wis, Cha) of its original form.

I would come to the conclusion, that as long as the new form was capable of speech, your speech would otherwise remain unchanged.